# Drupal Commerce: renew role / subscription

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

We are selling a product using Drupal Commerce that will renew yearly, but not automatically (expensive, users will likely use POs). Right now, after purchase, they will receive the appropriate role based on their purchase for 1 year.

If they pay before the end date, I would like them to get an additional, non-overlapping year.

I would like a solution that is independent of payment type because some things will be done manually.

Comment: how do u calculate whether a user's membership has expired?

Answer (score 2):

I had implemented such a solution before. There was a subscription for a year,two years & three years. The problem was how to maintain the subscription limit & how to extend it.

The solution was creating a hidden field within for every user. When a user first buys a package for a year we programatically make a entry of the end timestamp in the end field. When  he buys one more package the current timestamp value of the field is added by additional timestamp

```
timestamp = timestamp + 1years timestamp
```

or

```
timestamp = timestamp + 2years timestamp
```

Hope this helps you